# Is it possible to separately run image magick commands on certain pages in a pdf documents, then combine it all into one pdf?

Tags: pdf, text-editors, imagemagick, code

I'm a student and have exams coming up. I'm trying to remove solutions from some online resources I've found to study from. The solutions were all written in red text under Short Answer (SA) questions and the correct option was highlighted red in all Multiple Choice Questions (MCQ). I've found a lot of these quizzes to do and needed an efficient method to quickly strip away answers from each pdf.

I experimented with Image Magick and was able to design commands to clean up both the MCQ and SA sections. My current workflow involves separately cleaning up the MCQ and SA through two different commands and then combining the pdf into one again. Each quiz is structured as such MCQ(1), SA(1), MCQ(2) and SA(2). This means that I have to separate each pdf into four parts and then recombine them all for every quiz.

Here are my four commands for each section and the command I use to combine all the files

```
magick -verbose -density 1200 +antialias Workbook.pdf[5-13] -fuzz 30% -fill white -opaque #db3416 -fuzz 20% -fill white -opaque #eca7a4 -fuzz 0% -fill white -opaque #ededed SA1.pdf

magick -verbose -density 1200 +antialias Workbook.pdf[14-15] -fuzz 30% -fill #343434 -opaque #db3416 -fuzz 12% -fill #9a9a9a -opaque #eca7a4 MC2.pdf

magick -verbose -density 1200 +antialias Workbook.pdf[16-23] -fuzz 30% -fill white -opaque #db3416 -fuzz 20% -fill white -opaque #eca7a4 -fuzz 0% -fill white -opaque #ededed SA2.pdf

magick -verbose -density 1200 +antialias MC1.pdf SA1.pdf MC2.pdf SA2.pdf output.pdf
```

With eight quizzes in each unit and four units to study for, I'm going to save a considerable amount of time just being able to run all these commands in one go instead. I have tried to just slap them all (by removing 'magick -verbose' and the separate outputs from the latter three and removing the line breaks) but what that does is it actually runs all the commands on every page rather than working in the page ranges I've defined.

I would appreciate any guidance with this